# How to line pictures up Horizontally not vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm following a Youtube tutorial but unlike in the Video the Pictures are lining up beneath each other for me instead of next to...is any of this code the cause? I'm (almost) certain I'm following the Video along without changes

HTML

```css
.features{
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color:gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin:auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.features figure img {
  border:1px solid white;
  width:200px;
  box-shadow:black 0 0 10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:auto;
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="features">
  <figure>
      <img src="images/220220.png" alt="burger1">
      <figcaption>nr1</figcaption>

      <img src="images/200190.png" alt="burger2">
      <figcaption>nr2</figcaption>

      <img src="images/200188.png" alt=",burger3">
      <figcaption>nr3</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `image` and `figcaption` in separate `figure` tag

```css
.features{
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color:gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin:auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.features figure img {
  border:1px solid white;
  width:200px;
  box-shadow:black 0 0 10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:auto;
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="features">
  <figure>
      <img src="images/220220.png" alt="burger1">
      <figcaption>nr1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
      <img src="images/200190.png" alt="burger2">
      <figcaption>nr2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
      <img src="images/200188.png" alt=",burger3">
      <figcaption>nr3</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **separate** *figure* for each image and associated caption.

```css
.features {
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.features figure img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: black 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="features">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="burger1">
    <figcaption>nr1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure> <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/101" alt="burger2">
    <figcaption>nr2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/99" alt=",burger3">
    <figcaption>nr3</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```